# Get the selected list value from dynamically created order list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a created dynamic order list with class name as follows

```
    $orderList = $('.questOl');

    for(var i=0; i<questList.length; i++){
        tr.push('<li class="questList">' + questList[i].questText + '</li>');
        tr.push('<p>&nbsp</p>')                     
    }
    $orderList.append($(tr.join('')));
```

Then I want to get the list value when I selecting it. I have tried several code snippet in this website. It give undefined value. The closest attempt using this line of code.

```
var x = $('.questOl').find('.questList').text();
```

But it take all the value from the list. What I want is current selected value only. Any idea?

Comment: What's your starting HTML? What HTML do you (want to) end up with (what's the 'output')? In what way do you 'select' a list item, or a list value?

Comment: @DavidThomas I just saw your replay when i look back at my question. I feel so bad. Your are pointing my lack when posting question. I will improve next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things you can do :

1. Create li using dynamic element creating rather writing html. ( optional )

```
for(var i=0; i < questList.length; i++)
{
  tr.push('$('<li/>',
    { 
      class : "questList",
      text : questList[i].questText 
    }));
    tr.push('$('<p/>',  
    { 
      text : " " 
    }));
}
```

2. Getting the li value on selecting it.

   Since you are creating the elements dynamically, you can delegate a click event on the li you created and register it on the document level so that the document could listen to the markup.

```
$(document).on('click','.questOl .questList', function()
{
    var selectedLiText = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: This solve my problem. Thanks @DinoMyte. My code on the top already created dynamic list. And you has tech me another way. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could set an "id" to the `<li>` tags based on the iterator :

```
for(var i=0; i<questList.length; i++){
    tr.push('<li class="questList" id="quest-' + i + '">' + questList[i].questText + '</li>');
    tr.push('<p>&nbsp</p>')                     
}
```

And then access it like :

```
var x = $('#quest-1').text();
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

If you're using the `click` event to select the element of the list, you could get its value with a function like this :

```
$('.questList').click(function(){
    var x = $(this).text();
});
```

In this case, no need for "id" or "data" attribute.

PS : Correct me if I'm wrong but with data attribute, I think you'll have same problems to know witch id to use.

Comment: I think using the `data` attributes (https://api.jquery.com/data/) would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how it would know that the current id is what I'm selected. I mean if it have dynamic number of list.

Comment: I'm digging into `data` too.

Comment: What I has learnt that in 'data' we need to set the value. I has done that but it also need to set different class name. But still I cant access the value with different class name because I cant get the logic how it know that I'm selecting the current class. Btw, @DinoMyte code has solved my problem.

Comment: I see, I did add the `click()` function at the same time of the accepted answer. BTW, I'm glad you sloved this. Good luck with jQuery. ; )

Comment: Ya. Thanks @Adrien Leber for your effort. Thanks again.